# How to set spf record to let my 2 server send mail by my domain?

Tags: spf

Hi I'm using a directadmin server's hosting.
when my website send mail by php, it will use user@mydomain.com to send email out

but mydomain.com's email is hosting by google workspace

I was set to

```
v=spf1 include:mydomain.com include:_spf.google.com -all
```

but I got the error:

> The domain's SPF record could not be resolved within 10 DNS queries.

How can I create a SPF record included my server and google workspace's server?

Answer (score 3):

By adding `include:mydomain.com` to the spf record of `mydomain.com` you created an infinite loop. Leave it out, you want to use `a` or `mx` instead:

```
v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com -all
```

Note: you might want to use `~all` instead of `-all` until you verified that your SPF record is working.

Comment: Thank you so much, so I just change to "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com -all" and this will include mydomain.com for that? thanks

Comment: The `a` stands for the A record of your domain. If you send mails from that server that is correct. If you send mails from a different server you need to use that instead. If you only send mails from Google services and no other servers you don't need anything but the google include.